# Adium last message?

Tags: macos, adium, mirc

I need to quickly send messages with a little variation in IRC (ie, irc commands).

On windows/mirc, I can just click up and the chat input will fill with my previous message.

I'm currently using Adium, but it doesn't have this basic feature? Does anyone know how I can get this, or perhaps suggest a different client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can press `Option-UpArrow` to get the last message sent into your input box.

This is window/tab specific, i.e. you cannot use this to send the same message to a whole bunch of different people. Use the clipboard (i.e. copy&paste) for this, maybe in combination with `Option-UpArrow`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware whether Adium has that feature or not, but I know [Colloquy](http://colloquy.info/) does (and is a very nice IRC client in general).